# Protractor test with headless Selenium Webdriver randomly times out

Tags: selenium, firefox, webdriver, timeout, protractor

I am having intermittent failures when running Selenium headless in my 
server using xvfb. It works most of the times, but ~10% of runs it fails with this message:

```
[06:35:05] I/direct - Using FirefoxDriver directly...
[06:35:05] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
/opt/e2e/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/http/util.js:83
          Error('Timed out waiting for the WebDriver server at ' + url));
          ^
Error: Timed out waiting for the WebDriver server at http://127.0.0.1:54389/hub
    at Error (native)
    at onError (/opt/e2e/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/http/util.js:83:11)
    at Promise.invokeCallback_ (/opt/e2e/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:1329:14)
    at TaskQueue.execute_ (/opt/e2e/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2790:14)
    at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (/opt/e2e/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2773:21)
    at /opt/e2e/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2652:27
    at /opt/e2e/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:639:7
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:368:9)
From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
    at acquireSession (/opt/e2e/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:62:22)
    at Function.createSession (/opt/e2e/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:295:12)
    at Driver (/opt/e2e/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/firefox/index.js:271:38)
    at Direct.getNewDriver (/opt/e2e/node_modules/protractor/built/driverProviders/direct.js:71:26)
    at Runner.createBrowser (/opt/e2e/node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js:182:43)
    at /opt/e2e/node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js:255:30
    at _fulfilled (/opt/e2e/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:834:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/opt/e2e/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:863:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/opt/e2e/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:796:13)
    at /opt/e2e/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:556:49
[06:35:51] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 1
```

I am running Selenium Webdriver 2.53.0

My config (using Mozilla Firefox 46.0.1):

```
exports.config = {
    framework: 'jasmine2',
    directConnect: true,
    specs: ['specs/*.js'],
    capabilities: {
        browserName: 'firefox'
    },
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 40000,
        showColors: false
    }
};
```

Test is just opening a browser:

```
describe('Home page flow test', function() {
    it('should load home page', function() {
        browser.get('https://www.google.com');
    });
});
```

I am running Protractor with this command:

```
xvfb-run --server-args="-screen 0 1024x768x24" protractor --verbose
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using firefox version 47.0?

Comment: Mozilla Firefox 46.0.1, should I try to update?

Comment: No, there is a problem with Firefox 47.0 that requires you switching drivers. I though that might have been the problem, but since you're using 46.0.1 it isn't.

Comment: Kind of a strange error taking into account you are using `directConnect`..